# Apache spark job failed to deploy on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to deploy a spark job to my Yarn cluster but am getting some exception which I don't really understand why.

Here is the stack trace:

```
15/07/29 14:07:13 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
Exception in thread "Yarn application state monitor" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error asking standalone scheduler to shut down executors
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.stopExecutors(C oarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.stop(CoarseGrai nedSchedulerBackend.scala:2 66)
    at  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.stop(YarnClientSch edulerBackend.scala:158)
    at  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1644)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$$anon$1.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:139)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java
:1326) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:208)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.stopExecutors(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:257)
    ... 6 more
15/07/29 14:07:13 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
```

Here is my config:

```
              SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("SparkQueryApp")
             .setMaster("yarn-client")// "yarn-cluster" or "yarn-client"
             .set("es.nodes", "10.0.0.207")
             .set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
             .set("es.cluster", "wp-es-reporting-prod")     
             .set("es.scroll.size", "5000")
            .setJars(JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(Demo.class))
            .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

            .set("spark.logConf", "true");
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: I don't think setting master in driver code will work.

Comment: Sure it does. I get the same error when I run `spark-shell --master yarn-client`

Comment: any resolution for this?